# Vagrant multiple machines override

Tags: vagrant

I have a question related to Hashicorp Vagrant. I would like to create a multi environment machine. I was wondering if we could share common configuration for multiple machines then override each with the specific requirements.
Imagine I have the following vagrant file.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # 
  config.vm.define "webserver" do |webserver|
    webserver.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
    webserver.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.10"
    webserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get update"
    webserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: "script specific to web server "
  end
  
  # 
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.11"
    db.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get update"
    db.vm.provision "shell", inline: "script specific to db"
  end
end
```

As we could see, we have some commons. And I would like to know if it was possible to make it a little bit shoter and more flexible. Maybe there is a way to override?

Also, what if I have a third machine that is not ubuntu but red hat instead? Would that be possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by create a list of vm's you want to create. This is a very nice way to configure multiple machines in an easy to read way.

```
# List of machine specific details
nodes = { 
  "webserver" => ["10.0.0.10", "script specific to web server"],
  "db"        => ["10.0.0.11", "script specific to db"],

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Iterate over the machines
  nodes.each do | (name, cfg) |
    ip_address, script_name

    config.vm.define name do |server|
      server.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
      server.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip_address
      server.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get update"
      server.vm.provision "shell", inline: script_name
    end
  end
end
```